# Selenium - automated user interaction

Tags: selenium

Do you know if is possible to develop an automated user interaction that uses an Android application developed by me using Selenium? If the answer is negative. There is another tool to develop it?

Answer (score 0):

Selenium WebDriver is used for desktop web functional automation testing. In order to be used on Android you will need to use [Appium](https://appium.io/) (works with iOS as well).

It was already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34609265/selenium-web-driver-on-android) by the way.